# PULL DATA (count) FROM MONGODB AND DISPLAY IT in a web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to pull the number of documents in mongodb db and display it in my Application home page... I found this code that it works well but returns the list of all documents (users List):

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs }); }); });
```

I don't understand the part function(e,docs)!
I tried the following code to get the number of documents but it doesn't work:

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.count({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : count }); }); });
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:

You have to get the length from the callback docs..

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs.length }); }); });
```